# Highlight the row of the data after ticking the checkbox but with colors that varies from what type the data is under

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Good day!

I would like for some help on figuring out a formula, or script code that would highlight the row beside the checkbox after ticking it, but with highlight colors that varies between types of data it is under.

Currently, I am using this formula in google sheets : (   **=$G2=TRUE**   )

After ticking the checkbox, it does highlight the row beside it, but I want the highlight color to be different depending on the type of data it is under. What I  want is for the highlight color to change to **blue**, if it's "**Animations**", **red** if it's "**Music Videos**" and "**Videos**"to remain the same color.

I have attached a link to a screenshot below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9bkp.png)

And here is the link for the sheet for your reference.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e7nrU2F8E-iiUPsOaRd_VnSkwEfAlfmQoRLDpAQfPZE/edit?usp=sharing

If you guys can help me out, it would really be a big help.

Thank you in Advance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put more AND(...) and put more conditional rules to check multiple out come with more different colors

```
=AND($G2=TRUE,$A2="Videos") for green

=AND($G2=TRUE,$A2="Music Videos") for red

=AND($G2=TRUE,$A2="Animations") for blue
```

Comment: Thank you so much @zummon. It worked perfectly on my end.Have a great day ahead of you!  :)